# Why does Silverlight not support compiled Regular Expressions?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

The [Silverlight 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(VS.95).aspx) and [Silverlight 3 Beta](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(VS.96).aspx) framework do not support *compiled* Regular Expressions i.e:

```
RegexOptions.Compiled
```

I'd be interested to hear the reasoning behind why this is the case if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it comes down to same reason for many design decisions in Silverlight - that it was a framework feature that didn't survive cost/benefit analysis; whether the benefit of having the feature was worth the additional size of the core download.

Comment: would you mind telling me a bit more about what you say here?

Comment: The bottom line is that MS wanted a small download so that end users wouldn't be put off by a big, slow download. Every feature added to the framework adds to the download size.

Answer (score 3):

Since silverlight is cross platform, there is no guarantee that the application will be able to create a separate assembly either permissions wise, or capability wise on the executing machine.

Answer (score 1):

I just went through the new Silverlight 3.0 help files looking and they still have the same message:

> The implementation of the regular
>   expression engine in the .NET
>   Framework for Silverlight is identical
>   to that in the .NET Framework. The
>   single exception is that the .NET
>   Framework for Silverlight **does not
>   support compiled regular expressions**,
>   which are predefined regular
>   expression patterns that are stored in
>   stand-alone assemblies together with
>   dedicated regular expression engines
>   that process text using those regular
>   expression patterns.

I suppose they may have forgotten to update the help file, but I haven't heard any work in the blogs to suggest otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, this is the same documentation paragraph linked to in my question.  I have now edited the question to hopefully make things more clear.